# No network connection - Android-x86 on VMWare Fusion

Tags: android, android-emulator, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to come up with some kind of Android environment to use for development on Mac OSX.

It's proving quite difficult ( [Android emulator laggy on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946345/android-emulator-laggy-on-mac) ). On my macbook the Android emulator is so slow that it is unusable. Note, I'm trying to build a tablet app, which seems to make things worse.

So far the best performance I've found is just running the x86 port of Android via VMWare fusion.

The only problem is the darn thing keeps giving a "No network connection" message.

I don't know much about VMWare, but I'm guessing that Android wants to use the virtual wifi adaptor, but VMWare fusion only provides a virtual ethernet adapter.

The image I'm currently testing is **android-x86-3.2-RC2-eeepc.iso**

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boot up Android x86, hit Alt+F1 (shows the shell). Put `netcfg` into and you get a IP. 
Open a shell on, and write `adb connect <theipyougot>`into. 
Now you should see your Emulator via `adb devices` and in Eclipse.

It can be possible, to play around with the VMWare Network Adapters. On VirtualBox I use a `Host-only Adapter`.

Reference: http://www.android-x86.org/documents/debug-howto

If you cant get it working, take a look at virtualbox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With netcfg it just shows that eth0 is not connected. I.e. `eth0  DOWN   0.0.0.0/0`

I don't get why it's not connecting. My macbook is connected to my local network via wireless. DHCP is turned on my router. I've tried using the virtual NAT / Bridged / Host-only methods for connecting the VM to the network. Nothing seems to work.

I even tried Virtual Box, but it gives the same results as VMWare.

Comment: OK, I guess DHCP is not working for whatever reason. Networking is not my strong suit ;) I looked up the manual commands and got eth0 now working (http://code.google.com/p/live-android/wiki/networkhowto)

Comment: Thanks, giving you the tick cause you got me thinking about things and that's what helped me work it out. Plus, I hadn't actually learned what adb was yet, and now I can see that will work perfectly to debug my app via eclipse, straight onto the VM instance. Cheers.

Comment: `netcfg` was what I've searching for. I typed `ifconfig` instead. Well, android is not linux :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I try to use Eclipse connect to Android x86 setup in VMware several times. I found that it works well with Android-x86 2.2 for generic x86 PC. However, there are something wrong with `Android-x86 3.2`, it always show 127.0.0.1 when I set Bridged connection.

Comment: I am using 2.2.2 now and whatever network adapter I use on VM Ware Fusion 7 on OSX Yosemite it just won't connect to the web. Only localhost shows up too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
dhcpcd eth0;
dhcpcd eth1;

Comment: if `dhcpd` android replacement for `dhclient`?

Answer (score 0):

1. install android x86 on vmware
2. run android terminal write command "ifconfig eth0"
3. "adb connect IP address of the VM:5555"
   now run your app on vmware

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue on my Android 9.1 r6 to solve it I did the following (If your primary objective is to get internet connection on your guest android os):

1. Got to your virtual machine settings [Click on **VMWare Title Bar** and press **Ctrl + D**] or [Click on **Player** Button top left -> Select **Manage** -> **Virtual Machine Settings**]
2. On the settings popup, select | click on **Network Adapter**
3. Choose **Custom: Specific virtual network**
4. From the dropdown, select the **VMnet8(NAT)**
5. Click **Ok**
6. Restart or reboot your android machine and **virtual WIFI** will be enabled