# Can I select a particular Android Device Emulator from AVD using Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Is there a way when using Cordova CLI to select a particular emulated device from the Android Device Manager (AVD)?

I am working on a tablet app and a smartphone app at the same time and need to switch to different types of emulators because of the different form factors and screen resolutions?

I know it's not a particular coding question but perhaps there is some Cordova code I can run in terminal to make the emulation more specific rather than:

```
cordova emulate android
```

Which seems to pick the first emulator off the stack.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the `target` parameter like this:

```
cordova emulate --target=emulator-5554 android
```

To get the device name of your emulator ("emulator-5554" in this example), run `/platforms/android/cordova/lib/list-started-emulators.bat`

Comment: Thanks Keith. Your answer looks promising but I can't seem to run the bat file in MACOSX. Is there a way to do this? I don't suppose I could get the specific device name from the AVD?

Comment: You ripper! Got the name from the AVD Manager. Not ready for batch files :|

Now if only the emulator worked faster. Genymotion a better option?

Comment: Ahh yes the batch file only works for Windows. I think it's the only way to get the device name on Windows because I can't seem to find it via AVD Manager. Too bad, I'd prefer not to use batch files too!

Comment: I don't know enough to help you with the emulator performance but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946345/android-emulator-laggy-on-mac) will help.

Comment: On OSX. Just call `android list avd` from the command line. Found this by calling `android --help`

Comment: It should be noted, that `emulator-5554` works for already launched AVD (it can be listed with `adb devices` too). However when you want to target un-launched AVD, then the name from AVD Manager can be used.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs how long did your `cordova emulate` command end up requiring? My command prompt is currently hanging (i.e. just waiting!) after running: `cordova emulate --target=emulator-5554 amazon-fireos`. The `exec`'ed command showing in STDOUT is: `exec: adb -s emulator-5554 install -r "/Users/mec/Sites/iom/MTapp/platforms/amazon-fireos/out/path-to-apk.apk"`

Comment: @mecampbellsoup, I never usually had to wait that long but I was only emulating for a handful of Android devices and iOS. Maybe 5 min max? Sounds like yours is not working properly. Is there any other dependencies that might be holding it up?

Comment: @infografnet it works, as long as you swap spaces with "_". e.g `Pixel API 25` becomes `Pixel_API_25`

Answer (score 9):

If you run the following command you will get a list of all available devices:

```
cordova run android --list
```

[image]

Next you can emulate your app by running:

```
cordova run android --target="<Device_Name>"
```

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 4):

For me:

If you use OSX, you can open shell in /platforms/android/cordova/lib/ as stated, and write the next command:

```
./list-emulator-images
```

after you've gotten the emulator image name,

```
cordova emulate android --target="the name"
```

Answer (score 0):

*Moderators rejected my edit and said I should share as answer so -

On Linux (from your project folder) use the command:

```
/platforms/android/cordova/lib/list-started-emulators
```

(Note that there's no  `.bat` in the command), then look for the console output e.g. `emulator-5554`.  Then as above run:

```
cordova emulate --target=emulator-5554 android
```